# Add data to JavaScript Object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

So in normal Javascript you can execute this block of code fine:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj['one'] = {};

console.log(myObj);
console.log(myObj.one);
```

But you get this error in TypeScript `Property 'one' does not exist on type '{}'`

Is this just by design? (e.g. I'm expected to make my own classes for this)

Comment: Your code doesn't have anything to do with JSON. TypeScript performs static type analysis. So yes, the errors it gives you are by design.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know how to explain it. That's just the kind of data type I get back from an API response for example (res.json()).

Comment: A lot of people refer to normal `JavaScript` Objects when they say `JSON`. `JSON` refers to the actual human-readable text representation of that JavaScript Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[damitij07's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37900155/2601448) covers a bunch of ways to deal with this, but I want to point out my favorite for this kind of use case: [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).

```
interface myObj {
  one:any;
}
```

Now you can mark variables as the interface and Typescript will check to ensure the object meets the requirements. Pass it around as you would anything else like classes or such and it will vanish on compile. No extra work for the js engine, just compile time checking.

```
const myObjInstance:myObj = {one:0};
function foo(x:myObj):myObj { return x; }
```

And if you need the field to be optional,

```
interface myObj {
  one?:any;
}
```

Now Typescript won't complain if you don't assign to the field.

Final note, this all assumes you are trusting the object to be what you expect it to be. If you're getting this from something external, even if you own it, you should probably check at runtime if the structure is what you expect to avoid errors.

Answer (score 3):

Typescript introduces type bindings error when you write code something like this by predicting the type of object when you declare it.

```
var myObj = {};
myObj['one'] = {};
```

There are many suggested methods of solving or rather coding around this ambiguity:

Creating a class object and creating a instance.

```
export class myObj {
  one:any;
}

let myObjInstance:myObj = new myObj();
myObjInstance.one = {};
//
console.log(myObj);
console.log(myObj.one);
```

Another easy way to get around can be

```
//set type of myObj is any
let myObj:any = {};
myObj['one'] = {};
//no error
console.log(myObj);
console.log(myObj.one);
```

Or possibly if you want dynamic typecasting

```
let myObj = {};
//cast while assigning
(<any>myObj)['one'] = {};

//no error
console.log(myObj);
console.log(myObj.one);
```

Comment: This was very helpful thanx @damitj07 .